# How calc visible or not gameobject in camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How calc visible or not gameobject in camera? If it overlap then hide it I try use Phisics.RatCast, but need very often draw ray for proper work (its very expensize cost performance)/

Comment: in general you should not need to care for this yourself (apart of setting up layer masks and occlusion culling). why exactly do you need your own solution? also i never experienced raycasts to be super expensive, sure they cost, but theres way worse - also there are spherecast, capsulecast and physics.overlapsphere which might help you.

Comment: Oclussion culling work only for already build objects in scene. I generate meshes in scene in runtime

Comment: I want like https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/6391

Comment: you could look into quad/octrees for your purpose, in general read into space partitioning, a full answer with a complete solution is a bit much, i'm sorry. be warned though, if your generated meshes also move through the scene it gets quite tricky and is prone to end up with even worse performance.

Comment: All gameobjects with meshes is static